# Abstract Class getter and setter usage

Tags: java, object

I have a question in regards to how I am planning to create my abstract models, I am using an abstract class as the base class and then subclasses, is it fine to use it like this?

I did google and found some samples but none was exactly like how I am doing it.

```
public abstract class Vehicle {

    String type;
    String color;

    public  abstract getType();

    public abstract setType(String type);

    public abstract String getColor();

    public abstract setColor(String color);
}
```

And then in my subclasses, I could do something like this:

```
public class Truck extends Vehicle {

    String pickupBed;

    public setPickupBed(String pickupBed) {
        this.pickupBed = pickupBed;
    }

    public getPickupBed(String pickupBed) {
        return pickupBed;
    }

    public setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public getType(String type) {
        return type;
    }

    public setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public getColor() {
        return color;
    }
}
```

And another class, except cars, does not have a pickup bed.

```
public class Car extends Vehicle {

    public setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public getType(String type) {
        return type;
    }

    public setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public getColor() {
        return color;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the reason of having those methods abstract since they _can have_ defined behavior?

Comment: I guess my question would be, should non abstract getters and setters be defined there? as I have them in the sub classes?

Comment: Yes, they should. Your base class is simply a data bag and it declares two fields: `type` and `color`. It is _totally_ fine to declare those fields setters and getters in the base class only. Moreover, it's even a preferred way for simple data bags + you can make those fields `private` as they usually should be (therefore, the `Truck` would only add 1 set/get method pair, and the `Car` class would be empty (empty classes are not that bad in many cases)).

Comment: @fluffy makes absolute sense. I was basically stuck on whether I should fully define the getter + setters in the base class or just define them like how I have them now, and then write them out fully in the sub classes. Thanks a lot! if you dont mind revising what I have and posting it as an answer so I can accept it. I am sure others in the future might have this confusion. Regards

Comment: This is what inheritance is basically about. If you'd add another class that extends `Vehicle`, you'd be in trouble: you'd have to implement the whole set of the abstract methods for no real reason, including: 1) adding 4th, 5th and so forth classes would demonstrate that such design has flaws more and more; 2) implementing those methods like that in any subclass may be error-prone (or simply contain typos); 3) making the fields private encapsulates the _fact_ that the base class has those fields (methods can delegate the work to fields of _other type_);

Comment: 4) non-abstract methods can have additional code that might do something more than just referencing fields (logging, validating, whatever you'd like them to do). These four points just come to my mind now, but there are more downsides. In general, abstract methods should only exist when it is not possible to define the behavior for that type (abstract class or interface), but subclasses can do that.

Comment: I'd prefer to leave it as comments, not an answer, please. ^^

Comment: Thank you @fluffy you've been great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create abstract getter and setter only if you need change behaviour of getiin and setting for your variables. If all child classes use the same getter and setter realization - you need to create getters and setters in the abstract class:

```
  public abstract class Vehicle {

    protected String type;
    protected String color;

    public String getType(){
        return type;
    };

    public String setType(String type){
        this.type = type;
    }

    ........

  }
```

In any case, if you need to include any logic for setter/getter in the future - you may override existing getter/setter:

```
public class Car extends Vehicle{

  public setType(String type){
   if (type.equals("type1")){
       this.type = type + "_1";
   } else {
       this.type = type + "_2";
   }
  }

  public String getType(String type){
   return "{" + this.type + "}";
  }
  
 }
```

You need to add abstract methods only if you want to force class-child implement some logic, f.e:

```
   public abstract class Vehicle {

    protected String type;
    protected String color;
    
    public String getType(){
        return type;
    };

    public String setType(String type){
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getTypeDescription(){
        return "Type description: " + generateDescription();
    }

    protected abstract String generateTypeDescription();

    ........

   }

  

   public class Car extends Vehicle{
      String generateTypeDescription(){
          return "foobar";
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do everything in an abstract class that you can do in a normal class **except** creating a new object only by using a constructor.

This means that you can simply copy and paste the getters and setters from your subclass into your parent class.

Depending on your implementation goals and style ideas, you can even make these getters/ setters *final*, meaning that subclasses simply cannot override them. This would look something like that: `public final String getType(){...}`.

Answer (score -2):

Your super class(Vehicle)'s getter and setter shouldn't be abstract. Variables in the super class must be private or public.